# Understanding fetch() and async/await in node. How do you retrieve the body of the response and pass it up a level?

Tags: node.js, async-await, fetch-api

I am for the life of me trying to understand fetch()/async/await.  I want to be able to execute my async function, retrieve the response, and pass the response up.  However, the keys of my keyboard are all broken from banging my head on it.  Thank you in advance.

````
  async function makeCall() {
    var restHostConfig = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/ip")
    var body = await restHostConfig.json();
    console.log("First this: " + JSON.stringify(body)); // Prints {"origin":"IP address"} Nice!
    return body;
  }

  const callComplete = makeCall().then((response) => {
    console.log("Now this: " + JSON.stringify(response)); // Prints {{"origin":"IP address"} Okay!
    var resolve = JSON.stringify(response);
    return resolve;
  })

  // At this point, below should print {{"origin":"IP address"} right?  Wrong.  It is a Promise object in which I have no idea at this point how to resolve into the response body.

  console.log("Finally this log: " + retrieveResponse);  //  I get it if this is pleb status.```
````

Comment: Logging it inside the `then` handler is the right thing to do.  Imagine ordering a pizza:  Step 1) Order a pizza for delivery.  Step 2) I should have a pizza now, right?   **no** you have to *await the pizza's delivery*.

Comment: How can I make the then() handler pass the response up then?